# Verify a date in JavaScript

Tags: asp.net, javascript, validation, date

I need to do user validation of a date field, it should be in the format *yyyyMMdd* and should not be more than one year in the future. How would I go about doing this? Currently I only have a crude regexp which is insufficient.

```
function VerifyDate(source, args)
{
    var regexp = /^([1-2]{1}[0-9]{1})\d{2}([0][1-9]|[1][0-2])([0][1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|[3][0-1])$/
    var result = args.Value.match(regexp);     
    if(result) {
        args.IsValid = true;
    } else {
        args.IsValid = false;
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take the regex to check the format only. You can stay simple:

```
^(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})$
```

Then parse the date and check the range:

```
function VerifyDate(source, args)
{
  args.IsValid = false;
  var regexp = /^(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})$/;
  var daysInMonth = function (y, m) {return 32-new Date(y, m, 32).getDate(); };

  var ma = regexp.exec(args.Value);
  if (ma && ma.length == 4 && ma[2] < 12 && ma[3] <= daysInMonth(ma[1], ma[2]))
  {
    var diff = new Date(ma[1], ma[2], ma[3]) - new Date();
    args.IsValid = diff < 31536000000; // one year = 1000ms*60*60*24*365
  }
}
```

Comment: The code above accepts 20019999 since new Date() do NOT throw an exception in javascript if month>12 or day > daysInMonth(month).

Comment: Close but still not right... There are at least 2 more bugs: One of them is that all dates in December is considered invalid.

Answer (score 1):

new Date() don't throw an exception if month or day is out of range. It uses the internal MakeDay to calculate a date (see [ECMAScript Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) section 15.9.3.1 and 15.9.1.13). To make sure that the date is valid in the function below, the input is converted to integers who is converted to a date, and then the parts of the date are compared to the integers.

Since date uses MakeDay, the calculation of *maxDate* works even if *now* is the leep day (xxxx0229 will be yyyy0301 where yyyy=xxxx+1)

```
function verifyDate(args)
{
    var result=false,
        match = args.Value.match(/^(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})$/);
    if (match && match.length === 4)
    {
        var year = parseInt(match[1],10),
            month =parseInt(match[2],10) -1, // 0 = January
            day = parseInt(match[3],10),
            testDate= new Date(year,month,day),
            now = new Date(),
            maxDate = new Date(now.getFullYear() + 1, now.getMonth(), now. getDate()),
            minDate = new Date(1800,0,1),
            result = (
                 testDate.getFullYear() === year &&
                 testDate.getMonth() === month &&
                 testDate.getDate() === day &&
                 testDate >= minDate &&
                 testDate <= maxDate
            );
   }
   args.IsValue = result;
   return result;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I finally went with is a combination of your answers, I used datejs which seems pretty nice. Here is my final validation function. For some reason the month seems to use a 0 based index so that's why it says -1 in the .set().

```
function VerifyDate(source, args)
{
    args.IsValid = false;
    var regexp = /^(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})$/;
    var m = regexp.exec(args.Value);
    if (m && m.length == 4) {
        try {
            var result = Date.today().set({ year: Number(m[1]), month: Number(m[2]-1), day: Number(m[3]) });
            if (result < Date.today().add({ years: 1 })) {
                args.IsValid = true;
            }
        }
        catch (ex) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Months are identified by an integer in the range 0 to 11, inclusive." see section 15.9.1.4 in http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf

Comment: Nice, I did not know that before today and hadn't seen the ECMA specification either. But isn't there some javascript reference in a more easily digestable format somewhere? Like a web directory? Digging through a pdf is cumbersome at best.

Comment: The pdf is the authoritative technical resource. A more user friendly resource is http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/default.asp